# in weka, simpleEducationalLearningSchemes package not working

Tags: weka, id3

I'm trying to use ID3 algorithm in WEKA. I installed package. But id3 isn't activated.
[ID3 isn't activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub0cR.png)

How to activate this? and also how to activate OneR rule?
[oneR isn't activated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIo2r.png)

Comment: The tag `ID3` is about metadata container (for example in MP3 music files). I don't think this one fits to your question.

Comment: This is about the decision tree algorithm [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) developed by Ross Quinlan, not mp3 files.

Comment: @Rei Rosemary It is difficult to say anything without information about the attributes of your data set. At least if you can specify the data type of the inputs and outputs, we can produce solutions.

Answer (score 0):

ID3 only handles categorical attributes and class attribute. From the *More* dialog in the GenericObjectEditor, you can see the following capabilities:

- Class - Nominal class, Binary class, Missing class values
- Attributes - Binary attributes, Unary attributes, Nominal attributes, Empty nominal attributes

OneR can handle categorical and numeric attributes, but only a categorical class attribute. The capabilities from the *More* dialog:

- Class - Nominal class, Binary class, Missing class values
- Attributes - Binary attributes, Unary attributes, Numeric attributes, Nominal attributes, Date attributes, Empty nominal attributes, Missing values

Without knowing what your dataset looks like, I can only assume that you might have a class attribute that is of type *STRING* or *NUMERIC*.

If you want to use a certain algorithm, you have to preprocess your data accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be active at least for OneR? Because OneR can handle "Attributes - Binary attributes, Date attributes, Empty nominal attributes, Missing values, Nominal attributes, Numeric attributes, Unary attributes".

Comment: If the class is numeric, then no. OneR can only handle categorical class attributes.